# Internally connecting pins on microcontroller

Tags: lcd, gpio

I am working on generating passive LCD waveforms myself using a microcontroller, and am noticing that proper LCD driver hardware has only one set of resistor dividers for generating bias voltages and is able to arbitrarily "fan them out" to as many pins as they want. This requires specialized hardware to connect directly from M pins up to N other pins, right? (there's no easy way for me to emulate this, other than maybe PWM)

From PIC18F97J94 datasheet:

[image]

Comment: What kind of display you need to drive? Single common or multiple commons?

Comment: Multiple commons